# Android TV App creating picture from multiple HDMI inputs

Tags: android, television, hdmi

I want to create an app which can read all of the HDMI port inputs from devices such as game consoles for example and then combine the inputs into an image which would be displayed on the TV.

Is it possible to read all the TV's HDMI port inputs which come from the devices and which Java class (or native Android class in C++ if there is support for it) is used to get the image information.

Since some TV screens are quite big and can be 4k resolution then I would find it personally useful at least to be able to use that extra space/resolution to add another device'c input into the image shown.
Split screen with single TV with multiple devices for gaming.

I did not find [TV Input Framework](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/) helpful for finding out about this.

PS: Could 'app' be a tag?

Comment: I am not aware that you can process HDMI inputs, outside of a custom ROM. "PS: Could 'app' be a tag?" -- please, `$DEITY`, no.

Comment: A third party app is not able to take raw streams from HDMI inputs.

Comment: @Nick Felker. Would you make your comment an answer so I could mark it as a solution since it seems to be pretty definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third party app is not able to take raw streams from HDMI inputs on Android TV.

Comment: Is it possible to put overlay or PiP above an hdmi input stream ?

Comment: It will be possible with Android N: http://developer.android.com/preview/features/picture-in-picture.html